# $\dim(\ker\varphi\cap\ker\psi)=n-2$ proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over the field $K$. Let $\psi,\varphi$ be two non-zero functionals on $V$. Assume that there is no element $c\in K$,$c\neq 0$ such that $\psi=c\varphi$, Show that:
>
> $(\ker\varphi)\:\cap\:(\ker\psi)$
>
> has dimension $n-2$

I know $\dim V=\dim Im+\dim \ker$, in which $Im$ is image. We can apply this equation because $V$ is finite-dimensional.

$\dim(\ker\varphi)=n-1\\\dim(\ker\psi)=n-1$

If $\{v_1,v_2...v_n\}$ is a basis of V.

As we are dealing with linear functionals we can write:

$\varphi(v)=\langle v_i^{*},v\rangle$ in which $v$ stands for all vectors in $V$ and $v_i^{*}\in V^{*}$ the dual space.

$\psi(v)=\langle v_j^{*},v\rangle$ in which $v$ stands for all vectors in $V$ and $v_j^{*}\in V^{*}$ the dual space.

As $\psi=c\varphi$ for no $c\in K,c\neq 0$, so $v_i^{*}\neq v_j^{*}$

The orthogonal vectors in $V$ to $v_i^{*}$ are different from the orthogonal vectors in $V$ to $v_j^{*}$. So the statement is proven.$\blacksquare$

**Questions:**

**1)** Could someone check if my proof is right?

**2)** Is there any improvement recommended?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question says that there is no $c$ such that $\psi = c\phi$. In your attempt though you say "as $\psi=c\phi$ for $c \in K$.

Comment: @SahibaArora  Thanks! Please could you check my edit?

Comment: What do you mean by "the basis of $V$"?  There are many possible bases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know $\dim V=\dim Im+\dim \ker$

Then that's all you need.

**Hint:** Consider the map $T:V  \to K^2$ defined by $T(v) = (\phi(v),\psi(v))$.  Verify that $\ker(T) = \ker(\phi) \cap \ker(\psi)$.  Use the fact that there is no such constant $c$ to show that $\operatorname{Im}(T) = K^2$.

One approach is to note that
$$
\psi = c \phi \iff (c,-1) \in \operatorname{Im}(T)^\perp
$$

---

**Proof:** Consider the map $T:V  \to K^2$ defined by $T(v) = (\phi(v),\psi(v))$.  This is a linear map [show that this is true].  The kernel of $T$ is $\ker(\phi) \cap \ker(\psi)$ [show that this is true].  By the rank nullity theorem (that is, because $\dim V=\dim Im+\dim \ker$), we know that the kernel of $T$ has dimension at least $n-2$ and at most $n$.

Now, suppose for the purpose of contradiction that the dimension of the kernel of $T$ is at least $n-1$.  Then the image of $T$ has dimension at most $1$.  So, there exists a $c \in K\setminus \{0\}$ such that we can write
$$
\operatorname{Im}(T) \subseteq \{(x_1,x_2) \in K^2 : cx_1 - x_2 = 0\}
$$
(argue this part carefully!) However, this would mean that for all $v \in V$, we have 
$$
c \varphi(v) - \psi(v) = 0
$$
which would mean that $\psi = c \varphi$, contradicting our premise.

Comment: What does this $\psi = c \phi \iff (c,-1) \in \operatorname{Im}(T)^\perp$ mean? (c,-1)? Is my proof wrong?

Comment: Is $T(v) = (\phi(v),\psi(v))=\langle\phi(v),\psi(v)\rangle$?

Comment: First of all: $K^2$ is the set of all vectors of the form $(x_1,x_2)$ with $x_i \in K$.   $\psi = c \phi$ "if and only if the vector $(c,-1)$ is in the orthogonal complement of the image of $T$".  Yes, your proof is wrong, as others have mentioned, and as I have pointed out in my comment.  Finally, I don't know what the distinction is between $\langle \rangle$ and $()$ in your notation, so I don't understand the last question.

Comment: Oh, you edited your answer. I'll take a look.

Comment: $\langle\rangle$ is the inner product.

Comment: Your proof is still wrong because it is not necessarily true that $\ker\psi=\{v_1,v_2...v_n\}-v_a$ and $\ker\varphi=\{v_1,v_2...v_n\}-v_b$ given *any* basis of $V$; you would need to show that such a basis can be constructed.

Comment: @PedroGomes then $(\phi(v),\psi(v))$ is correct: $T$ takes in a vector from $v$ and produces an ordered pair.

Comment: Would you please finish your proof? I am having trouble following your line of thought. Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Please check my edit!

Comment: @PedroGomes your latest proof is incorrect.  First of all, if you define the basis without mentioning $\varphi$, then you can't circle back and decide that $\varphi(v) = v_i^*$.  Second, if $v_i$ is an element for your basis of $V$, then there is no clear meaning to your $v_i^*$.

Comment: @PedroGomes See my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

"If {v1,v2...vn}{v1,v2...vn} is the basis of $V$.

We know the $\ker ψ=\{v_1,v_2...v_n\}−v_a$ and $\kerφ=\{v_1,v_2...v_n\}−v_b$ ."

This sentence is false. An arbitrary basis of $V$ will not satisfy this.

Perhaps a good aproach would be using Riesz' Representation Theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem

Comment: Please check my update! See if my proof is right now, please.

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple concerns. Brace yourself!

1. There is no "the" basis for $V$. Most vector spaces have multiple bases (in most cases, infinitely many).
2. Unless you construct a basis $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ carefully, it may well be the case that $\phi(v_i) \neq 0$ for all $i$. Take for example, $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, $v_1 = (1, 0)$, $v_2 = (0, 1)$, $\phi(x, y) = x + y$.
3. I don't see what is gained by introducing the $\langle \cdot, \cdot 
   \rangle$ notation. Are you just renaming $\phi, \psi$?
4. "Orthogonal" doesn't mean much in this context. Are we an an inner product space?

Comment: I introduced the $\langle⋅,⋅\rangle$ notation, because it a linear functional so it works as a inner product.

Comment: 4. After the $\langle⋅,⋅\rangle$ notation is introduced, we know that ker(\varphi) depends on the elements in k that are zero. Therefore othogonality enters to ensure that the elements in $V$ that are orthogonal must be different hence the kernel is different.