# Proof of intersection of functional kernels to be $n-2$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over the field $K$. Let $\psi,\varphi$ be two non-zero functionals on $V$. Assume that there is no element $c\in K$,$c\neq 0$ such that $\psi=c\varphi$, Show that:
>
> $(\ker\varphi)\:\cap\:(\ker\psi)$
>
> has dimension $n-2$

I had published an proof of mine in [another thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349539/dim-ker-varphi-cap-ker-psi-n-2-proof?noredirect=1#comment4839345_2349539) but it was wrong. I would appreciate if someone could provide me a proof of the last theorem. I am self-studying, and my book has no solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is essentially the rank-nullity formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that's most intuitive to me would be to look at the restriction of $\psi$ to $\operatorname{ker} \varphi$. The result is a linear functional on this $(n - 1)$-dimensional subspace of $V$.

Suppose $\psi|_{\operatorname{ker} \varphi} = 0$. Then $\operatorname{ker} \psi \subseteq \operatorname{ker}\varphi$, and in fact equal, since neither is the $0$ functional, so both have dimension $n - 1$. If $(v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1})$ is any basis for the common kernel, then we may extend it to $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$, a basis for all of $V$. So, if we take an arbitrary element $v = \alpha_1 v_1 + \ldots \alpha_n v_n \in V,$ then we have,
\begin{align*}
\psi(v) &= \alpha_1 \psi(v_1) + \ldots \alpha_n \psi(v_n) = \alpha_n\psi(v_n) \\
\varphi(v) &= \alpha_1 \varphi(v_1) + \ldots \alpha_n \varphi(v_n) = \alpha_n\varphi(v_n),
\end{align*}
so $\phi(v_n)\psi(v) - \psi(v_n)\varphi(v) = 0$, i.e. $\psi$ and $\phi$ are linearly dependent.

Thus we cannot have $\psi|_{\operatorname{ker} \varphi} = 0$, so $\psi|_{\operatorname{ker} \varphi}$ is a non-zero functional on an $(n - 1)$-dimensional space, and hence its kernel has dimension $n - 2$.

All that's left to show is that $\operatorname{ker} \psi|_{\operatorname{ker} \varphi} = \operatorname{ker} \psi \cap \operatorname{ker} \varphi$, but this is straight forward.

It's not the quickest proof, with the most elegant tools, but I think it leads to some nice intuition about functionals. I hope it helps.

EDIT: Finishing off, as requested in the comments. It's almost too trivial to put into words, but let me try!

If $x \in \operatorname{ker} \psi|_{\operatorname{ker} \varphi}$, then $x$ must be in the domain of the function $\operatorname{ker} \varphi$, but also $\psi|_{\operatorname{ker} \varphi}(x)$ must agree with $\psi(x)$, so $\psi(x) = 0$, thus $x \in \operatorname{ker} \psi$, and so $x \in \operatorname{ker} \varphi \cap \operatorname{ker} \psi$.

On the other hand, if $x \in \operatorname{ker} \varphi \cap \operatorname{ker} \psi$, then $\psi(x) = 0$. Since $x \in \operatorname{ker} \varphi$, it follows therefore, from the definition of a restriction, that
$$\psi|_{\operatorname{ker} \varphi}(x) = \psi(x) = 0.$$
Thus $x \in \operatorname{ker} \psi|_{\operatorname{ker} \varphi}$, completing the proof.

Comment: Why is $\begin{align*}
\psi(v) &= \alpha_1 \psi(v_1) + \ldots \alpha_n \psi(v_n) = \alpha_n\psi(v_n) \\
\varphi(v) &= \alpha_1 \varphi(v_1) + \ldots \alpha_n \varphi(v_n) = \alpha_n\varphi(v_n),
\end{align*}$? Why $\alpha_n\varphi(v_n)$?

Comment: The first equality in each line is just using the linearity of the functionals. The second equality is using the fact that $v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}$ are in the common kernel of the two functionals.

Comment: Thanks for your proof, but I would like if you could finish $\operatorname{ker} \psi|_{\operatorname{ker} \varphi} = \operatorname{ker} \psi \cap \operatorname{ker} \varphi$? I am seeing it on my head but cannot translate it into language.

Comment: @PedroGomes Edited. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

I claim that $\ker \varphi=\ker \psi$ is not possible.

Suppose $\ker \varphi=\ker \psi.$ Since both have dimension $n-1,$ let $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_{n-1}\}$ be a basis for both. Let $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_{n-1},\alpha_n\}$ be the extended basis for $V.$

Since $\varphi(\alpha_i)=\psi(\alpha_i)=0$ for $1\le i\le n-1,$ we have $\varphi(\alpha)=t_1\varphi(\alpha_n)$ and $\psi(\alpha)=t_2\psi(\alpha_n)$ where $t_1,t_2\in K.$

Also since $\varphi(\alpha_n),\psi(\alpha_n)\in K$ are both non zero there exists $k\in K$ such that $\varphi(\alpha_n)=k\psi(\alpha_n).$ This implies that $\varphi=c\psi, c\in K$ which is a contradiction.

Hence $\ker \varphi\ne \ker \psi.$ This will imply that $V=\ker \varphi+\ker \psi.$

Now using the fact  $$\dim \ker \varphi+\dim \ker \psi=\dim (\ker \varphi\cap \ker \psi)+\dim(\ker \varphi+\ker \psi)$$

we get $\dim (\ker \varphi\cap \ker \psi)=n-2.$

Answer (score 2):

Using the rank nullity theorem, it is clear that the kernel of the functionals have dimension $n-1$ each, since the rank is of dimension $1$.

That is, the kernels of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ both have dimension $n-1$, so suppose that their orthogonal complements are respectively generated by elements $a$ and $b$ (i.e. the span of $a$ is the orthogonal complement of $\ker \varphi$, and likewise in the other case).

Suppose that $a=cb$ for some $c$. Then note that $\varphi = c \psi$ (check this by applying to any vector in $V$,and note that only some elements are *not* in the kernel).

Hence, $a \neq cb$ for any $c$. This tells us that $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent.

Note that $a$ is not in the kernel of $\varphi$, since it's in the orthogonal complement. However, $b$ is not in the kernel of $\psi$, for the same reason.

Hence, the intersection of the two kernels, avoids two linearly independent elements $a,b$, so it's of dimension less than or equal to $n-2$.

That it is equal to $n-2$, is deduced from the equality $\dim(V \cap W) = \dim V + \dim W - \dim(V+W)$, which I urge you to prove. Note that $\dim(V+W) \leq n$, so that $\dim(V\cap W) \geq \dim V + \dim W - n$. Put $V$ and $W$ as the respective kernels, and you will have the answer for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

it's worth mentioning that it's the more general result.

> Functional $f$ is linear independent of the other $f_1,...,f_n$ if and
> only if $\cap \ker f_i \subset \ker f$

That's a very useful result to keep in mind, as you see the condition on your post says $\varphi, \psi$ are not linear independent, and you see there is no inclusion relation between $\ker \psi$ and $\ker \varphi$ by the theorem above, therefore they do not equal.

---

Then apply the identity $\dim(V \cap W) = \dim V + \dim W - \dim(V+W)
$  will yield the result.