# Observing kernel dimensions of non-zero functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, dual-spaces

From Serge Lang's Linear Algebra:

> **(1)** Let $V$ be a vector space of finite dimension $n$ over the field $K$. Let $\phi$
>   be a functional on $V$, and assume $\phi \neq 0$. What is the dimension of the
>   kernel of $\phi$? Proof?
>
> **(2)** Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over the field $K$. Let $\psi$, $\phi$ be two non-zero functionals on $V$. Assume that
>   there is no element $C \in K$, $c \neq 0$ such that $\psi = c \phi$.
>   Show that:
>
> $$\textrm{Ker} \, \phi \, \cap \, \textrm{Ker} \, \psi$$

Both of these questions seem to be correlated, so I decided to put them together.

**Note**: I've seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2349539/513294) and there are few very interesting solutions (even in question, using Riesz-representation theorem but limited to Hilbert spaces), but in this case I wonder how valid my approach is.

## My attempts

**(1)** We know that $\phi: K^n \rightarrow K \neq 0$ where $V = K^n$. By the rank-nullity theorem, it can be observed that:

$$\textrm{dim} \, V = \textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Im}(\phi) + \textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Ker}(\phi)$$

We also know that $\textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Im}(\phi) \leq \textrm{dim} \, K$. **I will make a very important assumption here**:

$$\phi \neq 0 \implies \textrm{Im}(\phi) \neq 0$$

Thus by the assumption above, $\textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Im}(\phi) = \textrm{dim} \, K = 1$ (implying surjectivity), going back to rank-nullity:

$$\textrm{dim} \, V = 1 + \textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Ker}(\phi)$$
$$\textrm{dim} \, V - 1 = \textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Ker}(\phi)$$
$$\textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Ker}(\phi) = n - 1$$

Is my assumption valid?

**(2)**

We see that:

$$\psi: K^n \rightarrow K \neq 0$$

$$\phi: K^n \rightarrow K \neq 0$$

The question **(2)** assumes that:

$$\psi \neq c \phi, \forall c \in K$$ where $c \neq 0$.

From the solution above, it can be concluded that:

$$\textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Ker}(\psi)=\textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Ker}(\phi)=n-1$$

If $c \phi \neq 0$ and $c \neq 0$, then $\phi \neq 0$, thus I make assumption that $\phi(v) \neq 0$ and therefore considering that:

$$\textrm{Ker}(\phi) = \{v \mid \phi(v) = 0 \} = \emptyset$$

we can conclude that $\textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Ker}(\phi)=0$, and then apply formula:

$$\textrm{dim}(\textrm{Ker} \, \phi \, \cap \, \textrm{Ker} \, \psi) = \textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Ker} \, \phi + \textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Ker} \, \psi - (\textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Ker} \, \phi - \textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Ker} \, \psi)$$

$$\textrm{dim}(\textrm{Ker} \, \phi \, \cap \, \textrm{Ker} \, \psi) = 0 + (n - n) = 0$$

which makes no sense, because $n - 2$ is not the result..

## Question:

I'm trying to prove the question **(2)** with my solution, but I use the result from **(1)** to do so.

If result from **(1)** is correct, what's the problem with my solution for **(2)**, does it make any sense at all? Can it be modified to be correct, or should I stick with the solution from the [referenced question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2349539/513294)?

Thank you!

Comment: (1) is correct. Your solution for (2), however, is wrong at two places. $\dim\ker\phi=\dim\ker\psi=n-1$ by (1). What you'll need is $\ker\phi+\ker\psi=V$.

Comment: @Berci Wouldn't $\textrm{Ker}(\phi)+\textrm{Ker})(\psi)=V$ imply $(n - 1) + (n - 1)=(n - 1) - (n - 1) + \textrm{dim}(\textrm{Ker}(\psi)) + \textrm{Ker}(\phi))$? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is correct.

For (2), observe that $\dim\ker\phi=\dim\ker\psi=n-1$ by (1), so $\ker\phi=0$ is nonsense.

The dimension formula for the intersection and generatum (=sum) of subspaces correctly goes as:
$$\dim(A\cap B)+\dim(A+B)=\dim A+\dim B$$
for arbitrary subspaces $A, B$.

By the conditions, it is possible to prove $\ker\phi+\ker\psi=V$, whence
$$\dim(\ker\phi\cap\ker\psi)=n-2$$